# Pass Cancel or Update button click from popup back to parent page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I would like to get some help on a unique processing issue. I am looking for a specific solution given these constraints.

I have a popup aspx page that receives data from a parent page gridview Edit click. There is a great deal of parsing of data from parent page to pop up as the data is being translated in pop up, then sent back to parent page to be reassembled in the original text block before update.

When the popup passes the data back or is canceled, the parent page gridview is still in Edit mode.

I would like to pass the Cancel or Update button click from the popup to the parent page gridview so it can complete the update or cancel event without asking the user to click the corresponding command button link from the gridview edit mode, to Update or Cancel.

I am really looking for a tutorial, links or sample code as I want to fully understand how to do this.

UPDATE: There is also a jquery UIBlocker on the Parent page to prevent the user from returning to the page until the PopUp page processing has been completed. Below is the critical code:

**PARENT Page**:

```
function parentFunc(a) {
    //   Unblocks on return from popup page.
    $.unblockUI({});
    document.getElementById("<%=Textbox1.ClientID %>").value = a;

    alert("Please complete the update by entering a Brief Description then clicking the UPDATE link!!");
}

function parentCancel(s) {
    //   Unblocks because of cancel from popup page.
    // var a = 0;
    $.unblockUI({});

    alert("Please click the Cancel link to complete the Cancel process!!");
}
```

**PARENT PAGE Code Behind**, Row Updatinfg Event after building array of strings to pass to POPUP page.

```
' Sets up popup to open when row selected for edit is cycled.
If IsPostBack Then
    If (e.Row.RowState And DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 Then
        If Session("updateComplete") <> "Y" And Session("CancelUpdate") <> "Y" Then

            Dim BrowserSettings As String = "status=no,toolbar=no, scrollbars =yes,menubar=no,location=no,resizable=no," & "titlebar=no, addressbar=no, width=850, height=800"
            Dim URL As String = "NewpttStringPopUp.aspx"
            Dim dialog As String = URL
            Dim scriptText1 As String = ("<script>javascript: var w = window.open('" & URL & "','_blank','" & BrowserSettings & "'); $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Please translate text and click Submit...</h1>' });  </script>")

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(Page), "ClientScript1", scriptText1, False)
            Session("updateComplete") = "N"
        End If
    End If
End If
```

**POPUP Page**:

```
function closeform() {
     alert("Please click the Cancel Button at the buttom of the page to Cancel the process!!");

    return "Please click the Cancel Button at the buttom of the page to Cancel the process!!";
   }

function handleWindowClose() {
    if ((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY < 0)) {
        event.returnValue = "If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Save button, your changes will be lost.";
    }
}

function callParentFunc() 
{
    var w = window.opener;
    var a;
    if (!w.closed) {
        var val = w.parentFunc(a);
        self.close();
    }
    this.window.focus()
}

function callParentCancel() {
    var w = window.opener;
    var s;
    if (!w.closed) {
    var val = w.parentCancel(s);
    self.close();
    }
}
```

**POPUP.ASPX.VB  code behind  CANCEL BUTTON**

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ' Cancel Button so that no update is processed.
    ' Sets flag to prevent java popup from reopening after RowUpdating event. Occurs in RowDataBound event.
    'Dim s As String = "c"
    Dim strScript2 As String = "callParentCancel();"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "callParentCancel", strScript2.ToString, True)

    Session("UpdateEnd") = "Y"
    Session("CancelUpdate") = "Y"
    'Response.Write("<script>window.close();</script>")
End Sub
```

**POPUP.ASPX.VB  code behind  SUBMIT BUTTON**

Process of building the arrary is not displayed for breivity..

```
Session("returnTranslation") = arReturn

    '   Page.PreviousPage.Focus()

    Dim strScript As String = "callParentFunc();"
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "callParentFunc", strScript.ToString, True)

    ' Sets flag to prevent java popup from reopening after RowUpdating event. Occurs in RowDataBound event.
    Session("updateComplete") = "Y"
```

Had a problem with preventing the popup from reloading. So there is an if condition in the load event. A dynamic number of controls are built on the popup as literals. So the Page Init event and Page Load event fire on non Postback to rebuild the controls.

thanks, all suggestions will be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a JavaScript function on the parent, and use `window.opener` to access it from the popup:

**On the parent**

```
processGridCommand = function(command){
    __doPostBack("<%= GridView1.ClientID %>", command);
    return false; 
}
```

**From the child**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    updateParentGrid = function(command){
        if (window.opener){
            window.opener.processGridCommand(command);
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClientClick="return updateParentGrid('Update');" />
```

**Handling the postback on the parent**

This will trigger a postback on the parent, and overriding the `RaisePostBackEvent` method in the code-behind, you can handle it as needed:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);
    if (source == GridView1)
    {
        switch (eventArgument)
        {
            "Update":
                //perform update logic
                break;
            "Cancel":
                //cancel edit mode
                break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks James, I Updated the OP with my code. Could you take a look?